# How to copy a multidimentional string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I know that I must use memcpy multiple times if I had initialized my 2D string array dynamically but I have used the standard C compile time syntax to initialize the 2D string array in functions stack. However as I can't simply pass the pointer to the temporary stack memory area, I will have to use memcpy to copy the entire memory into a dynamically allocated space. However when I try to do it, I get a segmentation fault.

```
#include <string.h>

char ***simar (int *b, int *c) {
    //b=c;
    char a[10][10][100] = {{"hello","hey","bro"},{"huh", "hey","ouch"}};
    char ***d = malloc(sizeof(a));
    memcpy (d ,a , 100*10*10 * sizeof(char));
    //printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+0) + 0));
    return (char ***)d;
}

int main() {

int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[] = {4,5,6};
char ***d = simar(a,b);

    printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+0) + 0));
    printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+0) + 1));
    printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+0) + 2));
}
```

Secondly, I'm doing it the right way. What is the proper way of passing multidimentional string array in C among functions?

EDIT: I understand that my syntax looked offensive to C fans. I was just blinkered of using high level languages so much that I forgot the basics of pointers in multidimentional strings. Further I do agree with one of the comment down there that multidimentional is just abuse of language. We must call it pointer to array which contain pointers to array which contains pointers to strings really.

Comment: You are doing things horribly wrong. Better pick a C text book and study `pointers in C` and `strings in C`. If you still can't figure out how to do this, please ask your question here.

Comment: Just pass an array of `char *`, like `argv` of `main()`.

Comment: Also, why do you cast `d`?

Comment: What if I want to do it this way? What is the mistake

Comment: casting was not needed

Comment: Arrays and pointers are different, your `memcpy` is not even close to working. You have to allocate 110 pointers for this to work. And you don't use `b` and `c` in ` simar`.

Comment: When you hear someone talking multidimensional arrays in C or multidimensional strings in C (whatever the heck that would mean), run away. There are no such things. There are arrays of arrays, there are arrays of pointers, there are pointers that point to arrays, **these things are all different and not interchangeable** and you have to know one from the other. Lumping them under one "multidimensional" label is muddy thinking. There are multidimensional arrays as a high-level abstract concept, but you have chosen a low-level language. Deal.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void  *simar(void) {
    char a[10][10][100] = {{"hello","hey","bro"},{"huh", "hey","ouch"}};
    void *d = malloc(sizeof(a));
    memcpy (d, a, sizeof(a));
    return d;
}

int main() {
    char (*d)[10][10][100] = simar();

    printf("\n%s" , (*d)[0][0]);//hello
    printf("\n%s" , (*d)[0][1]);//hey
    printf("\n%s" , (*d)[0][2]);//bro
    printf("\n%s" , (*d)[1][0]);//huh
    free(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer, code only answers are considered bad.

Comment: A novice would be confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char ARR[10][100];

ARR *simar (void)
{
    char a[10][10][100] = {{"hello","hey","bro"},{"huh", "hey","ouch"}};
    ARR *d = malloc(sizeof a);
    memcpy (d , a , sizeof a);
    return d;
}

int main()
{
ARR *d = simar();

    printf("%s\n" , d[0][0] );
    printf("%s\n" , d[0][1] );
    printf("%s\n" , d[0][2] );

    free(d);    // thanks BLUEPIXY
}
```

If you need to have run-time sizes instead of the middle `10` and `100`, you cannot use this approach. You will have to switch to dynamically allocating an array of pointers which point to arrays of pointers which point to strings.  (Well, I guess you could use a 3-D VLA).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what I wanted. Basically as mentioned in the comments above we have to malloc pointer arrays which will dereference to stings. Regarding using contiguous space, we can redeclare the array so that compiler knows how much to skip when you can a+1 etc.

```
char ***simar (int *b, int *c) {
    b=c;
    //char a[][10][100] = {{"hello","hey","bro"},{"huh", "hey","ouch"}};

    char ***a;
    a = malloc (sizeof(char*) *2);

    *(a+0) = malloc (sizeof(char*)*3);
    *(*(a+0)+0) = malloc (sizeof(char)*10);
    *(*(a+0)+1) = malloc (sizeof(char)*10);
    *(*(a+0)+2) = malloc (sizeof(char)*10);

    *(a+1) = malloc (sizeof(char*)*3);
    *(*(a+1)+0) = malloc (sizeof(char)*10);
    *(*(a+1)+1) = malloc (sizeof(char)*10);
    *(*(a+1)+2) = malloc (sizeof(char)*10);



    strcpy(**a, "hello");
    strcpy(*((*a)+1), "hey");
    strcpy(*((*a)+2), "bro");

    strcpy(**(a+1), "huh");
    strcpy(*(*(a+1)+1), "hey");
    strcpy(*(*(a+1)+2), "ouch");




    //printf("\n%d\n" , sizeof(a));
    //char ***d = malloc(sizeof(a)*2);
    //memcpy (d ,a , sizeof(a));
    //printf("\n%d\n" , sizeof(a));

    //printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+0) + 0));
    return a;
}

int main() {
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int b[] = {4,5,6};

char ***d = simar(a,b);

printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+0) + 0));
printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+0) + 1));
printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+0) + 2));

printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+1) + 0));
printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+1) + 1));
printf("\n%s" , *(*(d+1) + 2));
}
```